# why do I receive wrong Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: theming, blocks

There is a view and content type both called `activities` and this is `views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php`

```
<div class="element">
<div class="image"><?php print $fields['field_activities_image']->content;?></div>
<div class="text">
    <div class="head"><?php print $fields['field_activities_title']->content;?>    </div>
    <div class="body"><?php print $fields['field_activities_summary']->content;?>    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

this block is displayed in the `front--page.tpl.php` and it works right.
There is another block of this view and that block is displayed in the node page. this block only contains 10 `title`. the problem is drupal reports this warning in the node page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_image in include() (line 2 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_summary in include() (line 5 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_image in include() (line 2 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_summary in include() (line 5 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_image in include() (line 2 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_summary in include() (line 5 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_image in include() (line 2 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_summary in include() (line 5 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_image in include() (line 2 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_summary in include() (line 5 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_image in include() (line 2 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
Notice: Undefined index: field_activities_summary in include() (line 5 of ...views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php)
```

The ID of the block that is displayed in the node page is `block_1` but it tries to use `views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php`. how can I solve this warning?

Comment: What `var_dump($fields)` shows you? Is this index defined at all? what was in auto-generated comment in the generated views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php file?

Comment: like I said there are two blocks of `activities` view, `block` and `block_1`. `block` contains the above mentioned fields but `block_1` only contains `field_activities_title`. `var_dump($fields)` displays the fields in the front page, but `summary` and `image` is not in the `block_1` that's why it reports this warning in the node page. `block_1` is not in the front page and there is no warning in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the name `views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php` is a suggestion for all blocks of the view activities - to get better specified template name check template information in that view. ('Information' link under Other -> Theme in the view builder) I *think* that the template name should be something like `views-view-fields--activities--[block_id].tpl.php`.

Change the `block` machine name if necessary.

Also, its a good practice to utilise this in templates to prevent such warnings:

```
<?php if (!empty($fields['field_activities_image'])):?>
  <div class="image"><?php print $fields['field_activities_image']->content;?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, `views-view-fields--activities--block.tpl.php` is shared among all of the blocks

Comment: yeah so change the block machine name to distinguish it.